# Hecke's estimate for $L(1,\chi)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

If I understand correcly, Hecke's proved that

$$L(1,\chi)=\frac{1}{O(\log|d|)}$$

> Is there a modern exposition of this result?

The most common textbooks in analytic number theory seem to prove at most Siegel's theorem.

Comment: if $\chi$ is not the exceptional character. see [Friedlander 2006 page 100](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Friedlander+J.B.%2C+Heath-Brown+D.R.%2C+Iwaniec+H.%2C+Kachorowski+J.+Analytic+number+theory..+Lectures+(LNM1891%2C+Springer%2C+2006)(T)(O)(223s)_MT_.pdf)